# Openmp lock alternative that allows concurrent reads until a thread tries to write?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I want to replace:

```
omp_set_lock(&bestTimeSeenSoFar_lock);
  temp_bestTimeSeenSoFar = bestTimeSeenSoFar; // this is a read
omp_unset_lock(&bestTimeSeenSoFar_lock);
...                
omp_set_lock(&bestTimeSeenSoFar_lock);
  // update/write bestTimeSeenSoFar
omp_unset_lock(&bestTimeSeenSoFar_lock);
```

with code that will allow multiple threads to be reading the variable at once UNLESS a thread is trying to write, in which case they wait until the write is done. Help?

Answer (score 0):

What about using something like this?

```c
#pragma flush( bestTimeSeenSoFar )
#pragma omp atomic read
temp_bestTimeSeenSoFar = bestTimeSeenSoFar;

...

#pragma omp atomic write
bestTimeSeenSoFar = whatever;
#pragma flush( bestTimeSeenSoFar )
```

My reading to the OpenMP standard [chapter 2.12.6](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf#G4.1466812) dealing with `atomic` doesn't permit me to decide whether this will perform exactly what you want, but this is the best / closest I can come up with. Moreover, even if this might work in theory, it will be highly dependant on the quality of the implementation of this feature within your compiler. So it not working for you won't necessarily imply that the idea is wrong.

Anyway, I would encourage you to give it a try and, please please, to report if it works for you.